# Why do I get this error when using the NPM link

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-link, notistack

I am learning the [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link/) and following the instructions.

The library I want to link is [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) and I can in the terminal do "npm link" and all is good.

When I do "npm notistack" to link the library in my project it looks OK like it works.

But when I do "npm start" I get this,

[image]

And in the notistack library I get this message when doing "npm run-script build"

[image]

In Win 10 project folder the dist folder looks like this

[image]

what am I missing to do?

### Update

I worked a couple of times now without the error but then I got this error again. I can't figure out why.

### Update

I have to restart laptop every time I update code and want to build. Maybe in the future it can be more effective, let's hope.

Comment: Add code as text